# Matrix multiplication

Tags: java, optimization, algorithm, matrix

Below is the code that I've written for matrix multiplication:

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MatrixMultiplication {

    private static final String TERMINATED_MESSAGE = "Terminated" + "," + " ";
    private static final String INVALID_MATRIX_DIMENSION_ERROR_MESSAGE = TERMINATED_MESSAGE + "Invalid matrix dimension!";
    private static final String MATRIX_MISMATCH_ERROR_MESSAGE = TERMINATED_MESSAGE + "First matrix column and second matrix row must be same!";
    private static final String INVALID_INPUT_ERROR_MESSAGE = TERMINATED_MESSAGE + "Invalid Input!";

    private static Scanner scanner;
    private static DecimalFormat decimalFormat; 

    private static int firstMatrixRows;
    private static int firstMatrixcolumns;
    private static int secondMatrixRows;
    private static int secondMatrixColumns;

    private static double firstMatrix[][];
    private static double secondMatrix[][];
    private static double resultMatrix[][];

    private static boolean errorFlag;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        initialize();
        if (!errorFlag) getInput();
        if (!errorFlag) calculateProduct();
        if (!errorFlag) displayResult();

    }

    private static void initialize() {

        scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.##");

        errorFlag = false;

        try {
            System.out.print("Number of Rows in First Matrix: ");
            firstMatrixRows = scanner.nextInt();

            System.out.print("Number of Columns in First Matrix: ");
            firstMatrixcolumns = scanner.nextInt();

            System.out.print("Number of Rows in Second Matrix: ");
            secondMatrixRows = scanner.nextInt();

            System.out.print("Number of Columns in Second Matrix: ");
            secondMatrixColumns = scanner.nextInt();
        } catch (InputMismatchException ime) {
            System.out.println(INVALID_INPUT_ERROR_MESSAGE);
            errorFlag = true;
            return;
        }

        firstMatrix = new double[firstMatrixRows][firstMatrixcolumns];
        secondMatrix = new double[secondMatrixRows][secondMatrixColumns];

        if (firstMatrixRows == 0 || firstMatrixcolumns == 0 || secondMatrixRows == 0 || secondMatrixColumns == 0) {
            System.out.println(INVALID_MATRIX_DIMENSION_ERROR_MESSAGE);
            errorFlag = true;
            return;
        } else if (firstMatrixcolumns != secondMatrixRows) {
            System.out.println(MATRIX_MISMATCH_ERROR_MESSAGE);
            errorFlag = true;
            return;
        }

        resultMatrix = new double[firstMatrixRows][secondMatrixColumns];

    }

    private static void getInput() {

        System.out.println("Enter the first matrix (" + firstMatrixRows + " x " + firstMatrixcolumns + ") :");
        readValues(firstMatrix);

        System.out.println("Enter the second matrix (" + secondMatrixRows + " x " + secondMatrixColumns + ") :");
        readValues(secondMatrix);

    }

    private static void readValues(double matrix[][]) {

        for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < matrix[0].length; j++) {
                try {
                    matrix[i][j] = scanner.nextDouble();
                } catch (InputMismatchException ime) {
                    System.out.println(INVALID_INPUT_ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    errorFlag = true;
                    return;
                }
            }
        }

    }

    private static void calculateProduct() {

        for (int i = 0; i < firstMatrixRows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < secondMatrixColumns; j++) {
                for (int k = 0; k < secondMatrixRows; k++) {
                    resultMatrix[i][j] = resultMatrix[i][j] + (firstMatrix[i][k] * secondMatrix[k][j]);
                }
            }
        }

    }

    private static void displayResult() {

        System.out.println("First Matrix:");
        printMatrix(firstMatrix);

        System.out.println("Second Matrix:");
        printMatrix(secondMatrix);

        System.out.println("Result Matrix (Product):");
        printMatrix(resultMatrix);

    }

    private static void printMatrix(double matrix[][]) {

        for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < matrix[0].length; j++) {
                System.out.print(decimalFormat.format(matrix[i][j]) + "\t\t");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println();

    }

}
```

What are your thoughts on this?  Can this code be optimized or done using any other simpler logic?  Any suggestions and thoughts are welcome.

Comment: I can't say much of the code, but all the input that you require for a simple multiplication seems to make this very uncomfortable to use (you even request the 'middle' dimension twice). Perhaps you could be inspired by the MATLAB notation, where multiplying 2 matrices is as simple as: `[1 2; 3 4]*[1 0; 0 1]`, or when you are in a verbose mood: `mtimes([1 2; 3 4],[1 0; 0 1])`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

## Static and void

**All** your variables are static. **All** your methods return `void`. This is not good.

Java is an object-oriented language. You're not using it that way. You're using it more as a procedural language by having everything as static and using only `void` methods. Although this works (apparently), you're losing flexibility.

I have a mission for you:

Remove all the below lines from your program and use them as **local variables** rather than static fields.

```
private static Scanner scanner;
private static DecimalFormat decimalFormat; 

private static int firstMatrixRows;
private static int firstMatrixcolumns;
private static int secondMatrixRows;
private static int secondMatrixColumns;

private static double firstMatrix[][];
private static double secondMatrix[][];
private static double resultMatrix[][];

private static boolean errorFlag;
```

To get you started I have some few suggestions:

- `displayResult` method can take three parameters: `firstMatrix`, `secondMatrix`, and, you guessed it: `resultMatrix`.
- `calculateProduct` can take two parameters: `firstMatrix`, `secondMatrix`, and **return** the result matrix.
- `getInput` can be modified into only reading one matrix, then you can use `getInput("Enter the first matrix", firstMatrix);`
- Use `firstMatrix.length` and `firstMatrix[0].length` to determine the width and height of a matrix.

#### Your own Matrix class

And finally, this is a major suggestion that partially goes against the above suggestions:

Replace `double[][]` with `MyMatrix` that you [create as your own class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/).

- The `MyMatrix` class itself can contain the `getInput` method and a `public MyMatrix multiply(MyMatrix otherMatrix)` method.
- It can also contain `double[][] matrixData`
- The class can contain an `output` method for outputting it's internal `matrixData`.
- It can also contain, if you want, `private final int columns;` and `private final int rows;`

This is what I would ultimately recommend, as it will allow you to add an `add` method, and a whole lot of other matrix-specific methods such as `calculateInverseMatrix`.

## Constants

The only variables I can accept being `static` are the ones marked `final` (the constants). I would however make a minor change to one of them, as there's no meaning to use string concatenation here: `"Terminated" + "," + " "`.

```
private static final String TERMINATED_MESSAGE = "Terminated, ";
```

## Use exceptions rather than `errorFlag`

```
    if (firstMatrixRows == 0 || firstMatrixcolumns == 0 || secondMatrixRows == 0 || secondMatrixColumns == 0) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(INVALID_MATRIX_DIMENSION_ERROR_MESSAGE);
    } else if (firstMatrixcolumns != secondMatrixRows) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(MATRIX_MISMATCH_ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
```

Throwing an exception is to be used for exceptional cases. You should perhaps consider [creating your own Exception class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8423700/how-to-create-a-custom-exception-type-in-java), and ask yourself if you want it to be a [checked or unchecked exception](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=129).

Once you have created your own `MyMatrix` class and restructured your program a bit to use more object orientation (remember my challenge, get rid of all those static variables!) I hope that you will write a follow-up question and that I will say "Well done! You did it!".